# jQuery Cloned table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with an Add button at the end. When you click this button a new row is getting cloned. I am able to clone the rows but since I have columns that are initially disabled and get enabled from a drop-down column. The problem I am getting is if the columns are disabled initially a new row with a disabled row is adding up but when I enable the row by selecting the values from the drop-down the columns of the new row are already enabled which I want to be disabled.

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.Buttons', function() {
  var $tr = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
  var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
  cindex++;
  $clone.find(':input').val('');
  $clone.attr('id', 'id' + (cindex)); //update row id if required
  //update ids of elements in row
  $clone.find("*").each(function() {
    var id = this.id || "";
    if (id != "") {

      var match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 2) {
        this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
      }
    }
  });
  $tr.after($clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id01" name="row">
      <td>


        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}" />

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Le2t6k/)

Comment: I don't exactly undestand but you're cloning a table row with disabled input fields. Where do you enable the input fields?

Comment: Through 'Select' whenever i change the value it gets the field enabled by assigning the value of "disabled=false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clone when you set input value as empty string

```
$clone.find(':input').val('');
```

you need to set attribute as disabled

```
$clone.find(':input').not('select').val('').attr('disabled', true);
```

Note: I have added .not('select') so the select box doesn't get disabled